# Create a Numpy array with an Arbitary shape, (prefereably without for loops)

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

I am attempting to map the Topology of my neural network using numpy.

I am looking for a method to create an irregularly shaped array preferably without the use of for loops.

The code below creates a numpy array of objects. the array is an irregular shape and will change based on the "Iarray" variable passed in.

The topology of my Neural net is [2,3,2] so this function outputs a array with three columns, 2 elements in the first, 3 elements in the second, and 2 elements in the third.

```
 def object_array(Iarray):
     Array = np.empty([1,len(Iarray)],"object")
     Cell_Chain = np.empty()
     for i in range(len(Iarray)):   
         row = np.array([LSTM.Cell(i,ii) for ii in range(Iarray[i])])    
         Array[0,i] = row
     return Array
```

This is clunky looking, and I would very much like to find a better way to write this code.

If anybody has an idea, I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: "I am looking for a method to create an irregularly shaped array" - then NumPy is probably a bad choice of tool. Why not use a list of lists? What benefit do you hope to gain by using NumPy? Whatever benefit you hope to get, you're probably not going to get it.

Comment: `np.empty()` produces an error.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: An irregullarly shaped array, or rather an object dtype array containing arrays of varying shape, is a clunky object, so creating it will also be clunky.  As will processing it!

Comment: As I understand I am able to control the datatypes in numpy to reduce memory, I also understand that normal python lists store pointers and not the actual value. I need this to be as efficient as possible. The reason I don't use a regular shaped array is because in my finished product, i will have over 800 inputs with not nearly that many hidden neurons. as a result i feath that a 800x16 array will take to much time to run through.

Comment: You are not going to receive any of those benefits with the array you're trying to create. NumPy's memory advantage only works with native dtypes and regular, grid-structured arrays. For an irregularly shaped collection of LSTM cell objects, a list of lists will work far better.

Comment: With object dtype the array stores 'pointers' just like lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to create an object dtype array:

```
In [550]: arr = np.empty(5, object)                                                                    
In [551]: arr                                                                                          
Out[551]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

You can fill it from a list of objects:

```
In [552]: arr[:] = [np.arange(i) for i in range(5)]                                                    
In [553]: arr                                                                                          
Out[553]: 
array([array([], dtype=int64), array([0]), array([0, 1]),
       array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

in fact you can create the array directly from the list:

```
In [554]: np.array([np.arange(i) for i in range(5)])                                                   
Out[554]: 
array([array([], dtype=int64), array([0]), array([0, 1]),
       array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)

In [555]: np.array([np.arange(3) for i in range(5)])                                                   
Out[555]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Assignment to the predefined array is more reliable:

```
In [561]: arr[:]=[np.arange(3) for i in range(5)]                                                      
In [562]: arr                                                                                          
Out[562]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]),
       array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Occasionally you can have broadcasting errors in such an assignment.

But in any case, you still have to create the objects that you are going to assign to the array, and it's hard to avoid loops when doing that - at least not in the most general cases.